# Using replace() in Fragment Transaction consume more Memory than add()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very new for using Fragments in Android. I have developed an app using Fragments but it is causing OutOfMemoryError. I have used replace() for changing fragments. My Fragments contain expensive UI Components and thinking that using replace() causing it such error as when I come back to Fragments it will create the UI again and again. Using add() method will reduce Memory consumption? I came to such conclusion after android documentation where it state add method will add the fragment container while replace will remove all the ui part of earlier fragments.

Answer (score 2):

*Add/replace* methods destroy and create fragments from beginning, causing the entire fragment's life-cycle to kick-in. In your case, I would suggest you to use *attach/detach* methods which cause not to reserve additional memory.

Read more about these methods in [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: adding fragments to container using add() and if we use show/hide will not cause entire fragment's life cycle. Will it be good for my case.